# Windows Installer Errors for Clients (Management and Monitoring Tool)

Tags: windows-7, installation

So I build installers for clients for Windows 32 or 64 bit systems. Some of my clients are getting the following error when attempting to run the installer on Windows 7.

> This installation requires the following windows component:
>   management and monitoring tool. This tool is either missing or did
>   not execute properly

I attempted to google for this supposed tool but to no avail. The customers are adamant that no such tool exists in their programs list. Does anybody have any ideas on how to go about solving this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Windows 7 N does not come with all the packages that normal Windows 7 does. This does not solve the problem, but at least the source is known.